# Plot series of filled hexagons in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to create a tesselation of filled hexagons (polygons centered around a hexagonally-spaced lattice) in ggplot2. I have accomplished this using the 'plot' command but am struggling transitioning this to ggplot.

Here is the code for the set-up:

```
# Generate a lattice of points equally spaced in the centers of a hexagonal lattice
dist = 1     # distance between the centers of hexagons
nx = dist*15 # horizontal extent
ny = dist*15 # vertical extent      

MakeHexLattice = function(nx, ny, dist, origin=c(0,0)) {
  locations = cbind(location = 1:(nx*ny),
                    x = sort(c(rep(seq(from=0, by=dist, length.out=nx),each=ceiling(ny/2)),
                               rep(seq(from=dist/2, by=dist, length.out=nx),
                                   each=floor(ny/2)))) + origin[1],
                    y = rep(c(seq(from=0, by = dist*sqrt(3), length.out=ceiling(ny/2)),
                              seq(from=dist*sqrt(3)/2, by=dist*sqrt(3),
                                  length.out=floor(ny/2))) + origin[2], times=nx))
  class(locations) = c(class(locations), "lattice")
  attr(locations, "gridsize") = dist
  return(locations)
}
```

Here is the code for creating the image using 'plot', which looks very nice:

```
landscape = MakeHexLattice(nx=nx,ny=ny,dist=dist,origin=c(0,0))

# Plot hexagonal lattice as points
plot(x=landscape[,2],y=landscape[,3], pch=19, col="black", cex=0.5, asp=1/1)

# Separate x and y coordinates
lx = landscape[,2] # x-coordinates
ly = landscape[,3] # y-coordinates      

# Plot hexagonal lattice as filled hexagons
hex.x = cbind(lx + 0, lx + 0.5, lx + 0.5, lx + 0, lx - 0.5, lx - 0.5) 
hex.y = cbind(ly - 1/(sqrt(3)), ly - 1/(2*sqrt(3)), ly + 1/(2*sqrt(3)), ly + 1/(sqrt(3)), ly + 1/(2*sqrt(3)), ly - 1/(2*sqrt(3)))
hex.vectors = cbind(hex.x, hex.y)

for(i in 1:(length(hex.vectors)/12)){
  polygon(x=hex.vectors[i,1:6], y=hex.vectors[i,7:12], angle = 120, border=NULL, col="wheat", 
          lty = par("lty"), fillOddEven = FALSE)
}
```

Any tips on how to accomplish this same thing using ggplot2 (which I am transitioning to using)? I have tried using geom_polygon but can't seem to work out the for-loop. (Also, please don't tell me to use 'hexbin' -- not the goal that I am trying to accomplish!)

Thank for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with most things in ggplot, the plotting is actually extremely straightforward, most of the work is getting your data in the right shape so that it makes sense. A `for` loop is entirely unnecessary, `geom_polygon()` just needs a dataframe with the x and y coordinates, and a variable defining which group they belong to. With your data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

#Get your coordinates in long format with an id
hexdat.x <- melt(cbind(id = 1:length(hex.x), as.data.frame(hex.x)), id.vars = "id", value.name = "x")
hexdat.y <- melt(cbind(id = 1:length(hex.y), as.data.frame(hex.y)), id.vars = "id", value.name = "y")

#Merge them into the same dataframe
hexdat <- merge(hexdat.x, hexdat.y)

head(hexdat)
#   id variable    x          y
# 1  1       V1  0.0 -0.5773503
# 2  1       V2  0.5 -0.2886751
# 3  1       V3  0.5  0.2886751
# 4  1       V4  0.0  0.5773503
# 5  1       V5 -0.5  0.2886751
# 6  1       V6 -0.5 -0.2886751
```

Now to plot the hexagons, you just need to give `ggplot` the x and y coordinates, and specify the group each one belongs to:

```
ggplot(hexdat, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(group = id), fill = "wheat", colour = "black")
```

[image]

Comment: I had no idea you could do this with ggplot! Thanks @alexwhan!